# Why is this modulo equation wrong when it shouldn't?

Tags: python, modulo

Why isn't q equal to b as the formula for modulo is: a % b = a - (a/b)*b ?

```
x = (int(time.time())*100)
q = x % 360
b = x - (x/360)*360
print(x)
print(q)
print(b)
```

Comment: `a - (a/b)*b` equals `a - a`, which equals `0`, you're probably looking for `//`

Comment: `(x/360)` is doing float division, try `(x//360)` for integer division